# How to import Carthage framework directly to the project in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, cocoa-touch, carthage

I want to use Carthage dependency manager in my project. Due to security reason I'm not able to install the library through brew/package. Instead I got the Carthage library and it's having two files CarthageKit.framework and carthage exec files.

I've added the framework in the project and given the path in Framework Search path but it's not working. Don't know how to proceed it further. Can you please help me out.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: You are not able to install Carthage in your mac?

Comment: Yes Deepak, due to security reason my company won’t allow me to install it.

Comment: Then you can’t use Carthage. Just install the library manually. Many third party libraries include instructions on how to do it manually. If the library in question doesn’t provide such instructions and you cannot figure it out, let us know which library it is and we might be able to help.

Comment: @Rob is correct, if you need to use 3rd party framework, download the framework and add it to your project.  (Just in case if you already got CocoaPods installed, you can use it as well as your dependency manager)

Comment: @Rob, As I mentioned earlier I’ve used the Carthage in many of my project. I got the carthagekit.framework library directly and they instructed me that no need to install the Carthage library through brew/package. Now I’ve the carthagekit.framework library with me. I’ve followed the two normal steps like I’ve imported the carthagekit.framework file to the project and gave the framework in project settings. Just want to know is that possible to use Carthage library through direct carthagekit.framework file. Thanks